# size image in an imageview in PagerActivity

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I am using this project [universal-image-loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).I would like to know how can I get the size of an image displayed in the pagerActivity?

I added this two line in ImagePagerActivity.java (after imageLoader.displayImage(...){})

```
imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()
imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()
```

But the result is 0 and 0.

I also tried to use this in ImagePagerActivity.java  (I change the getImageSizeScaleTo to public in ImageLoader):

```
ImageSize targetSize = imageLoader.getImageSizeScaleTo(imageView);
```

But the size is always width:540 height:960 whereas my images don't have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image size by using the following methods

```
 // Getting the size of the Image inside the ImageView and The size will differ based
 **// on the image you placed inside the ImageView

  ImageView imageObj = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
  int imageWidth = imageObj.getWidth();
  int imageHeight = imageObj.getHeight();
```

### Or It might help, you can try this :

```
  int imageWidth = imageObj.getMeasuredWidth();
  int imageHeight = imageObj.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but I still have 0 and 0 as result.

Comment: Ok my bad, I put this in the wrong place, but it seems to get me the size of the real image and not the image printed in my screen